# Maintain margins for drawing after window resize

Tags: cocoa, math, graphics

I'm writing an application draws in another application's window  (this is under OS X with Cocoa, but the question is general enough that I hope it won't be bogged down by operating system / framework issues), and I'm running into a problem which seems like it should have a simple answer, but it's driving me absolutely insane.  Here's the problem:

I draw a rectangle inside another application's window which has to be in a certain location relative to the top and left of the window (i.e. the margins between my rectangle and the top & left of the target window must remain fixed).  I can calculate the relative x,y coordinates required as a percentage of the window's size, which works fine:  the rectangle shows up correctly.  However, the user then resizes the window, and I can resize the rectangle correctly by using a transformation based on the ratio of the new height and width to the old height and width, but I lose my relative positioning:  the rectangle's coordinates are now incorrect (see image - this is a rough mockup of the problem).

[image http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/5273/resizeexample.png](http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/5273/resizeexample.png)

Now, I can't figure out how to calculate the new x,y coordinates relative to the top and left of the window.  The window isn't square; its resize is constrained by the other application, but the aspect ratio width / height changes by some unknown function.  When I measure the required y coordinates in relative terms, the percentage changes when the window resize.  Numerically, it looks something like this:

Before resize:  
window size:  h=>760, w=>546
rectangle origin: x=>355, y=>84  (e.g. 84/546 = 15.3% of height)

After resize:
window size:  h=>1009, w=>717
rectangle origin should be: ? (I can measure it as something like x=>474,y=>99, but I can't *predict* those values;  99/717 now = 13.8% of height).

I've tried every ratio of the two windows' measurements I can think of;  I've also run across the idea of translating to the origin, scaling, and then translating back to avoid the problem of scaling moving the coordinates - but I don't know where to translate back to! This probably has some simple geometric / trigonometric solution, but nothing occurs to me no matter how many diagrams I draw.  I'm willing to accept the inevitable embarrassment of someone pointing out some one-line solution to this problem if they can just point me in the right direction here!

Comment: “I draw a rectangle inside another application's window …” How are you doing that?

Comment: Sorry, that sounds weird the way I wrote it.  I'm not drawing directly into their window, I'm just creating a new window over the specified coordiantes (NSWindow with the level set to NSStatusWindowLevel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity:  I really have no idea how Apple (or anyone else) does this - and honestly, I think the application I'm trying to interact with was not written with this in mind anyways, since it is far from accessible.  To solve the problem, I just ended up sampling a whole bunch of different (x,y) pairs and constructing a linear model to predict the right coordinates for arbitrary coordinates.    A little bit of a sledgehammer, but it's the best I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be `left` units from the left and `top` units from the top, then try the origin as:

> x: `left`
>   y: `window.frame.size.height - rectangle.frame.size.height  - top`

Comment: But ... I don't know what top is after the window resizes.  That's the unknown quantity.  Or am I missing something here?  I can position the rectangle before the move as 546 + 84 (origin is in the top left), but after the window resizes, I only have the new height as 717.  The new origin should be 717 + x, but I don't what to set x as to keep it the same relative distance from the top as before.  (I measured it as 99, but I don't know how to calculate that value from what I have.)

Comment: Didn't you want to keep the distance from the top constant?

Comment: The margins are constant, but the distance from the top isn't because of the window resize. I don't know how to explain it better than this, which is probably part of the problem. In Interface Builder, it looks like this in the autoresizing controls: http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/7292/ibexample.png, though I'm only concerned about the top and left. Note how the margins remain the same even though the window resizes; if this were my own app, Cocoa would do that for me, but I'm faced with having to calculate this myself now, and I'm having trouble.

Comment: So you want constant height, proportionally growing top and bottom margins, and constant left and right margins?

Comment: The rectangle has to remain in the same position relative to the top and left, so the margins (expressed in pixels from the top and left) have to change to keep it there, e.g. if it were in the center, the top and left have to change so that the rectangle stays in the center.  I was calling them "constant" because I was thinking visually, but you're right in that the margins are actually growing / shrinking as the window resizes.  (The bottom and right aren't important for this problem - the window has a minimum and maximum size).

Comment: In other words:  I need to know what distance (in pixels) to set the top of the rectangle from the top / left of the window in order to correctly set the margins to keep the rectangle in proportionally the same place, as in the IB example diagram.